# Finding the ellipsoid of maximum area inside a square - and extension to $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: geometry, optimization, area, volume, convex-geometry

In an answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/12452/maximal-ellipsoid), I read that:

> Take a max area ellipse. Apply an affine transform to make it a circle; **then the problem becomes** to show that a minimal area parallelogram containing a circle is a square. It is easy to see that both the height of the parallelogram and its base are at least the diameter. Q.E.D.

I understand the second half of the reasoning here, but I don't understand why the original problem is **equivalent to** its reformulation in terms of a *min-area parallelogram*. Could someone help me achieve this **reformulation**, please?

Some comments read:

> **Comment 1:** By the way, the argument seems easy to adapt for cubes of any dimension.
> **Comment 2:** When you go to higher dimensions, you might as well prove Auerbach's lemma in general, since the proof is elementary and simple, and remark that Auerbach's lemma for the Euclidean ball gives John's theorem for the cube.

From my understanding, this is how this argument adapts to $n$-dimensions: Perhaps we'll be finding the min-volume parallelepiped that contains the $n$-ball of radius $1$, and noticing that the *base* of the parallelepiped along the $k$th dimension (for all $k$) is at least as large as twice the radius of the ball should complete the proof.

However, what is **Comment 2** saying?

Comment: To your first question: an affine transformation preserves the ratio of areas.

Comment: I see, I did not know that. It's obvious now. How do you prove this though? Start with saying that an affine transformation $f$ does the following: $$f:x\mapsto Ax + b$$ where $A$ is a matrix and $b$ is a vector.

Comment: Yes. The simplest way is to consider transformation of a unit square. You will find that the area of the image is $\det A$.

Comment: Ah, perfect! I suppose after mapping $x\mapsto Ax+b$ we can just calculate the Jacobian of this transformation, which I guess would be $\det A$? What if $A$ is not invertible though?

Comment: Not invertible affine transformation will decrease the dimension of the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding of your opening question and of comment 1 now seems fine. So we have a Theorem and Proof along the following lines. (Which I will state in the 3D form for simplicity.)

**Theorem** An ellipsoid of maximal volume inscribed in a cube is a sphere.

**Proof** Consider an ellipsoid of maximal volume inscribed in a cube and transform it into a sphere, of diameter $d$ say, by directional scalings. Then the cube is transformed into a parallelepiped containing the sphere. The parellelepiped has volume at least $d^3$ and so, by minimality it is a cube.

The point of **Comment 2** is that the above theorem even in $n$-dimensions can be generalised further. In particular, we can replace "inscribed in a cube" by "inscribed in a centrally symmetrical convex body".

**n-dimensions**

The crux of the argument comes at the end of the proof summarised above. For any direction, the $n$ -dimensional parallelepiped will lie between two planes perpendicular to that axis and a distance $d$ apart. So it's $n$ -dimensional volume is at most $d^n$.

Comment: I'm slightly concerned that you may now already have understood all this. If so, let me know that this adds nothing to your understanding and I will delete the post.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you add more details related to Comment 2? and how the argument adapts to cubes of any dimension?

Comment: Will do but I type slowly!